# Change 3D object color

Tags: javascript, html, colors, 3d

I am new to this site and am a beginner at web design/programming. I have been using some of the html5 tutorials available on the web. I am wondering if there is a way to change the color of a 3d object in html5? If I have a 3d cube, can I do an object "onclick" and generate a menu with maybe 5 color choices? I can make a blue cube red by clicking on it, but what if I want to have a few choices? I want to click on a 3d object and have several colors to choose from. Is this doable with javascript or does it require something more complex? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use

```
<div id="cube"></div>
<script>
    var cube = document.getElementById('cube')
    cube.style.backgroundColor = ((VALUE))
</script>
```

But if you have any problems with it I will try to work it out.